# ¿Cómo iniciar un programa con un carácter distinto?

Tags: java, gramatica-libre-de-contexto

Lo que estoy haciendo es un árbol de derivación pero no se como hacer que pueda empezar con un carácter distinto y que además siga el orden que tiene la cadena insertada por el usuario, en la parte inferior adjunto ejemplo de entrada y salida

```
        String A = "b";
        String aaA = "aaBB";
        String S = "d";
        String a = "a";
        String A1 = "A";
        String B = "dcd";
```

> ```
>     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
>     String str = sc.nextLine();
>
>     char[] charSearch = {'A', 'S', 'B'};
>
>     if (str.contains("A") || str.contains("B") || str.contains("S")) {
>         for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
>             char chr = str.charAt(i);
>             for (int j = 0; j < charSearch.length; j++) {
>                 if (charSearch[j] == chr) {
>                     if (str.contains("A")) {
>                         System.out.print("a" + A);
>                     }
>                     if (str.contains("a")) {
>                         System.out.print(a);
>                         break;
>                     }
>                     for (int o = 0; o < str.length(); o++) {
>                         if (str.contains("S")) {
>                             System.out.print(S);
>                             break;
>                         }
>                     }
>                     for (int k = 0; k < str.length(); k++) {
>                         if (str.contains("aaA")) {
>                             System.out.print(aaA);
>                             break;
>                         }
>                     }
>                     for (int l = 0; l < str.length(); l++) {
>                         if (str.contains("a")) {
>                             System.out.print(a);
>                             break;
>                         }
>                     }
>                     for (int m = 0; m < str.length(); m++) {
>                         if (str.contains("B")) {
>                             System.out.print(B);
>                             break;
>                         }
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 }
>                 break;
>             }
>             break;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Ejemplos de Salida

ASB = abddcd (Este si me sale, pero el ejemplo de abajo me da esta misma respuesta y no la invierte)

BSA = dcddab

Comment: En la condicional cuando es A tu devuelves "a"+A  ,osea ab por eso aunque inviertas ASB -BSA ,la variable A te devolverá ab

Comment: Cuando modifico la condición retirando la concatenación, no me detecta A ni S, solo B y me muestra dcd